# How do I format my vue document to change with window sizing?

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to Vue, this is my first time using it instead of just regular old HTML or CSS with some Javascript thrown in.
How do I format it so that it adjusts to the size of the screen it's being displayed on? My media queries don't seem to be doing anything.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Home msg="AutoSentinel"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Home from './components/Homepage.vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    Home
  }
}



</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
body{
  margin:0px;
}

</style>
```

```
<template>
  <div class="Home">
    <div class="top-bar">
      <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
      <div class="nav-bar">    
          <button @click="$router.push('about')">Home</button>
          <button @click="$router.push('about')">Drowsiness</button>
          <button @click="$router.push('about')">SOS</button>
          <button @click="$router.push('about')">Map</button>
          <button @click="$router.push('about')">Drivers</button>
          <button @click="$router.push('about')">Data</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main-page">
      <div class="greeting-wrapper">

          <p class="p1">
            Welcome to AutoSentinel
          </p><br>
          <p class="p2">
            Where driving meets safety
          </p>

          <div class="map">
            <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2964.9888949227957!2d-87.81797538455504!3d42.0005138792127!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x880fb63b7755aae1%3A0x4a77c1865fe64ca0!2sPanoskin!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1608611108029!5m2!1sen!2sus" width="650" height="350" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0"></iframe>
          </div>
      </div>

        <div class="driver-photo">
          <img src="../assets/MicrosoftTeams-image.png" width="300px" height="600px">
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>




<script>
export default {
  name: 'Home',
  props: {
    msg: String
  }

}

</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>

.top-bar{
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #8b1be6;
  color: black;
  box-shadow: -6px 0 white, 6px 0 white, 0 7px 5px -2px #d4d3d3;
}

h1{
  font-size: 90px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 0.3em;
}


.nav-bar{
  margin-top: 38px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.main-page{
  font-size: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 15px;
  background-image: url("../assets/backgroundline.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}


.map{
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.p1 {
  margin-left: 20px
}

.p2 {
  margin-top: -40px;
  margin-left: 105px;
}

button {
   background-color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: black;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.driver-photo {
    padding-right: 70px;
    padding-top: 30px;
}



</style>
```

Added code, sorry for forgetting that. I was trying to use a media query in this (not sure if I'm using Vue completely correctly here, either). Is there a way to make it dynamically adjust to the screen size?

Comment: Please share the code which doesn't seem to work. Without it, we can't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use media queries
You said media queries isn't working but from your code you aren't even using it.

You can read us on media queries here
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

The fact that you are using vue.js doesn't change how you're would implement media queries. Just use it the regular way you would in a regular HTML and CSS environment.

Comment: I took them out because they weren't working, but I'll try again! Maybe I just mistakenly typed something wrong somewhere.

Comment: Alright. You can read articles online on how to use media queries (I recommend you use the link I posted)...... Even if you've used media queries it's common to forget the syntax or even spell a word wrongly and since this is CSS we are dealing with its sometimes difficult to debug.... So check the syntax and spellings.

Comment: I was able to semi-get it working. I'm still working through debugging some issues, but it was a very helpful read, thank you! Now I just have a problem with two menus displaying when I change the screen, but I'll get it there!